# need assistance applying foreach statememt

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a script that references two separate csv files for employee info. The script will search for an employee first and last name and return an employee code from csv1 and state which company they are with if they are found in csv2. I want to be able to run both lines of code for each employee found that fits the search criteria when a wild card is used. The script works when only one employee is found. I cant seem to figure out how to get the last two statements to run for each item found in $res.

```
$csv1 = import-csv .\employees.csv
$csv2 = import-csv .\companyB.csv
$First = read-host 'What is the users first name?'
$Last = read-host 'What is the users last name?'
$res = $csv1 | Where-Object { $_.'last name' -like $Last -and $_.'First Name' -like $First } 
$res1 = $csv2 | Where-Object { $_.'last name' -like $Last -and $_.'First Name' -like $First }

if($res -eq $null) { Write-Host "User does not exist" }
else { $res | Select-Object 'Payroll Department Number','Last Name','First name' }

if($res1 -eq $null) { Write-Host "User is a Company A employee" }
else { Write-Host "User is a Company B employee" }
}
```

Comment: Does **employees.csv** contain ALL employees for both Company A and B? Does **companyB.csv** contain unique identifiers such as (presumably) the Payroll Department Number?

Comment: Please consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Employees.csv contains both company employees. Companyb.csv does not contain payroll #s. It is only used to determine which company the employee is a part of

Comment: I'd be more likely to help if this script contained an MCVE.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, this code will reproduce the issue when multiple employees are found. Can I attach csv files for testing?

Comment: This is an example of the output:                                                      Payroll Dept    Last     First                                                                 
D11210        Mat         Michael                                                                   
D11211        Midge     Michael                                                                  D11214        Mother    Michael                                                                
D11217        Mute       Michael                                                              User is a company B employee